# Why is Spotify taking up so much space but saying it isn’t on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage, spotify

In my storage settings I can see Spotify is taking up around 30gigs of space.

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
[image: Settings General Storage]

But… I‘ve already dumped the cache and removed any downloads.

[image: Spotify storage data]

Is Spotify lying or is iOS? Anyone know how to solve this problem?

For reference I’m on 15.3.1 on an iPhone 12 Pro.

Comment: Have you rebooted the phone?